# Referencing Stateless widgets in tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this simple screen:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

import 'CLWidget.dart';

class CLWebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CLWebViewWidgetState createState() => _CLWebViewWidgetState();
}

class _CLWebViewWidgetState extends State<CLWebViewWidget> {

  UniqueKey key = UniqueKey();

  @override
  void initState() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
        CLWidget('http://192.168.100.13:5500/index.html', key: key, requestAdHandler: () async {
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((value) {
            //Get reference to CLWidget
          });
        },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to get the reference to the CLWidget inside the requestAdHandler callback. I have tried to use a key as we do for statfull widgets but no luck.

How can I reference the widget from inside the callback?

Comment: What do you need to do by getting reference to the widget. I'm sure there is a "flutter" way of doing whatever you are trying to do without referencing the widget.

Comment: Call a method on the widget.

Comment: That's probably a good thing.  Smells like a misdesign.  Please explain what you are *really* wanting to do.

Comment: As @RandalSchwartz said, if you could provide the bigger picture of what you really want to achieve, we should be able to guide you to the right direction. For example, if you want to just call a function after 5 second delay, you should convert `CLWidget` to a stateful widget and do it inside `initState` of `CLWidget`. "Getting a reference to a widget" is not how you do things in Flutter.